# WSGIScriptAlias seems to disable apache ssl

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, wsgi

I have a django app that I'm trying to serve over a secure connection. Apache's ssl engine and my certificate are definately working, as my static media is served over a secure connection.

However when a request comes from django, firefox suddenly says the site is not secure.

My vhost looks like this (with simplified paths):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName  my.site.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile      /path/to/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /path/to/privatekey.pem

        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        Alias /static/myapp/ /path/to/myapp/static/

        WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/myapp.wsgi

        ErrorLog /path/to/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /path/to/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas why this might happen/what I can do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ye gods, made a stupid error there.

Firefox is saying the page is not secure because I'm linking to jquery from a cdn, which of course isn't secure!

If I put jquery in my static files Its all fine.

Feel a bit silly.